# JOGL Double Buffering

Tags: java, graphics, jogl

What is eligible way to implement double buffering in JOGL (Java OpenGL)?

I am trying to do that by the following code:

```
...    

/** Creating canvas. */
GLCapabilities capabilities = new GLCapabilities();
capabilities.setDoubleBuffered(true);
GLCanvas canvas = new GLCanvas(capabilities);

...

/** Function display(…), which draws a white Rectangle on a black background. */
public void display(GLAutoDrawable drawable) {
    drawable.swapBuffers();

    gl = drawable.getGL();

    gl.glClear(GL.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    gl.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

    gl.glColor3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);

    gl.glBegin(GL.GL_POLYGON);
    gl.glVertex2f(-0.5f, -0.5f);
    gl.glVertex2f(-0.5f, 0.5f);
    gl.glVertex2f(0.5f, 0.5f);
    gl.glVertex2f(0.5f, -0.5f);
    gl.glEnd();
}

...

/** Other functions are empty. */
```

Questions:

— When I'm resizing the window, I usually get flickering. As I see it, I have a mistake in my double buffering implementation.

— I have doubt, where I must place function *swapBuffers* — before or after (as many sources says) the drawing? As you noticed, I use function swapBuffers (`drawable.swapBuffers()`) *before* drawing a rectangle. Otherwise, I'm getting a noise after resize. So what is an appropriate way to do that?

Including or omitting the line `capabilities.setDoubleBuffered(true)` does not make any effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If JOGL is like the C/C++ version:

RMorrisey and the sample code is incorrect in stating the use of glFlush.

The swapBuffers function must go at the end of the drawing.

To confirm this: have the shapes do animation very quickly and watch for tearing. If you get tearing then you are doing a single draw, if you don't then you are using double buffering.

Comment: If you get tearing it may just be that the buffer swapping is not synchronized with the screen refresh.

Comment: Double buffering is designed to intentionally avoid that. Rather directly draw onto the screen, the results are cached in the background and then the new memory segment is shown on the screen.

Comment: What Steven says is true... but only if you do what finnw says.  In JOGL, this is accomplished by the (default: on) AutoSwapBufferMode in GLDrawable (in case the OP manually shut it off elsewhere in code).

Comment: that sounds like something that the Java version would do. You should be double bufferring anyways

Answer (score 7):

If you use a GLCanvas, autoSwapBuffer mode is set to true by default, you should not have to call swapBuffers() manually. Your flickering has nothing to do with double buffering, rather set sun.awt.noerasebackground to true.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of double-buffered animation using JOGL:

http://www.java-tips.org/other-api-tips/jogl/how-to-implement-a-simple-double-buffered-animation-with-mouse-e.html

Try instead of calling swapBuffers(), at the end of display(...) call:

```
gl.glFlush();
```

It's been a while since I've done anything with JOGL; hope this helps.

Comment: You need both.  glFlush flushes the polygon pipeline, drawing everything to the video buffer.  But you still need to swap buffers to make the result visible on the screen.